# MS Access open Excel file forcing link updates

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Using Access/Excel 2010.

This code is running off an account I don't have direct access to, so I can't mess with any Excel settings. I'm just making the code.

I am trying to get MS Access to open a workbook, and sometimes it'll give a prompt asking to update links/refresh data/etc, and I want to automatically say yes to this (rather than having the process get hung up or proceed with stale data).

This is the code I use now:

```
If objXLT Is Nothing Then
    Set objXLT = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

Set xlWBk = objXLT.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
```

where `objXLT` and `xlWBk` are Objects.

How can I force it to do the `.Open` with automatic updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dox on [`Workbooks.Open` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx), use the `UpdateLinks` property:

> Specifies the way external references (links) in the file, such as the reference to a range in the Budget.xls workbook in the following formula =SUM([Budget.xls]Annual!C10:C25), are updated. If this argument is omitted, the user is prompted to specify how links will be updated. For more information about the values used by this parameter, see the Remarks section. If Microsoft Excel is opening a file in the WKS, WK1, or WK3 format and the UpdateLinks argument is 0, no charts are created; otherwise Microsoft Excel generates charts from the graphs attached to the file.

The values you can provide:

> 0: External references (links) will not be updated when the workbook is opened.
>
> 3: External references (links) will be updated when the workbook is opened.

In your code:

```
Set xlWBk = objXLT.Workbooks.Open(file_name, UpdateLinks:=3)
```

Comment: Any time I open up a link from that website, I get a blank white page. Really frustrating to not be able to read the official docs. Thanks!

Comment: Try different browser(s) or version of your browser possibly?